# Getting input from the user in Lua

Tags: input, lua

How can I get an input from user in Lua (like `scanf` in C)?
For example, the program ask user his name, then he writes his name, then the program will output his name.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use io.read() Beware that the function can be customised with different parameters. Here are some examples.

```
 s = io.read("*n") -- read a number
 s = io.read("*l") -- read a line (default when no parameter is given)
 s = io.read("*a") -- read the complete stdin
 s = io.read(7) -- read 7 characters from stdin
 x,y = io.read(7,12) -- read 7 and 12 characters from stdin and assign them to x and y
 a,b = io.read("*n","*n") -- read two numbers and assign them to a and b
```

---

docs:

- io.read (···)
  Equivalent to io.input():read(···).
- file:read() args
  https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-file%3aread

Answer (score 12):

The simplest input can be retrieved using `io.read()`. This will read a single line from the standard input (usually the keyboard, but can be redirected e.g. from file).

You can use it like this:

```
io.write('Hello, what is your name? ')
local name = io.read()
io.write('Nice to meet you, ', name, '!\n')
```

`io.read()` is just a shortcut for `io.input():read()`, similarly `io.write()` is a shortcut to `io.output():write()`. [See the API for `read()` here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-file%3aread).

Notice that `io.write()` will not auto-terminate your line like `print()` does.

Comment: I would suggest using `io.stdin:read` instead of assuming that the default input file is `stdin`. Similarly with `io.stdout:write`.

Answer (score -2):

```
print ('Hello, make a face, ')
local face = io.read()
io.write('Nice, ', face, '!\n')
```

Comment: the name is just replaced as a face