# Is there an input and output function in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, input, output

I am new to PowerShell and I wanna try out a "Hello, (name)." program. Problem is I can't find an input function nor an output one.

Is there a PowerShell function I can use to get input like `input` in Python and output like `cout` in C++?

Comment: have you read the `Tour` page for this site? [*grin*] you are in violation of the rules by not posting code that "doesn't work as expected".

Comment: as for output ... anything not assigned to something will be sent to the success/output stream. there is no dedicated `output` method. however, there are several `Write-*` cmdlets. i recommend you read the `Get-Help` info on them.

Comment: `input` also lacks a dedicated method. there are, however, the `Read-*` cmdlets ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey First, I did read the tour page. Secondly, I don't know how PowerShell works yet and I can't find a way to get the input and output, but I guess cmdlets will help. Third and lastly, I actually did the same thing as this question: [Getting input from the user in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069109/getting-input-from-the-user-in-lua) which I think that I probably didn't violate the rules.

Comment: [1] reading all the way thru the tour page normally gives you 100 reputation points. you only show 5 ... so something went wrong. [*grin*] ///// [2] i showed you a clear hint about `Read-*`. i recommend you ReadTheFriendlyManual ... `Get-Command *read*` and `Get-Help Read-Host`. ///// [3] i also pointed out how to get the equivalent of `print` via the various `Write-*` cmdlets. again, take a look at the help system for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$User = Read-Host -Prompt "Name"
echo "Hello $User"
```

Powershell support many languages.

Comment: please, DO NOT post images of code. why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: you are very welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... and to see your actual code. [*grin*]

Comment: Also "gal echo" and "gal gal".

Answer (score 1):

There is another way, Write-Host.